# Annoying notebook scrolling on Ubuntu

Tags: notebooks, ubuntu

I hope this is the right place for my question.

I've been struggling with annoying scrolling with my Mathematica 11.0 on Ubuntu 17.04.. It is sluggish and clicky, on Windows it works fine instead. Does anyone know how I can try to fix this?

Comment: try a different windows manager, e.g. gnome. And try to update to 11.1